# How to get touch events in a view under action bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity with a header and a webview, and the action bar (split).

I need to show the menu at the bottom of the app, so I use the split action bar. Because of that, the action bar has to be active/visible. The action bar is made fully transparent, as I need to show a very customized header and I cannot use the native action bar.

Then, I show an alert in the header when the app receives a push notification. And I need to get touch event in the alert as there is an action related to the alert. **But I cannot get the click event because the action bar is over the alert, although it is transparent.**

**Code**

```
    Manifest:
    <activity 
        android:name="WebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
    </activity>

    Style:
    <style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>

    </style>
```

**Question**

- Is there any way to show only the split action bar but not the main one (top)?
- Is there any way to propagate the click event to a ui element under the action bar?
- Is there any way to get the click event over the whole action bar?

Comment: Just another way, Try to show popup instead of alert

Answer (score 0):

Options to solve the problem:

Popup.
Using a popup as @Abhi suggested seems to be ok but the menu option cannot be showd while the popup is active, so it cannot be used.

Activity type dialog.
Using a activity like a dialog allows to show the alert seems to be ok as popup but the menu option cannot be showed while the activity is active. Nevertheless, using the following flag window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
the user can interact with the parent activiy, so it could be ok if you do not use the native menu.

Example of the activity dialog configuration:

```
  <activity android:name="NotificationAlertDialog"
      android:label="titulo"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

**Solution**
At the end, I used the simplest solution. I only remove the split action bar and show a popupmenu manually. In this way, the alert view can be clicked, as there is no action bar over it.